# This webpage has a redirection loop

Tags: php

I have created a `member.php` and this page can only be accessed after the user has logged in the right credentials. If not it will redirect them to `index.php`. This is the code

```
<?
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Prime Time</title>
<link href="member.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="loadmessages.js"></script>
<?php
if ($_SESSION['username']){ 
    session_start();
}
else
header('Location:http://website.com/website/index.php');
ob_end_flush();
?>
</head>
```

However when I run this I get the error `"This webpage has a redirect loop"` (Chrome) 
Whats wrong with the code? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<?
session_start();
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Prime Time</title>
<link href="member.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="loadmessages.js"></script>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){ 
    header('Location:http://website.com/website/index.php');   
}   
ob_end_flush();
?>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

[sarcasm on]Silently updating the question is always great![sarcasm off]

Since you do not redirect to member.php over and over again this will do not cause the error.

But like @MikeBrant stated you have another one in your code:

You have to start the session before you work with it.

So currently you always redirect to the `index.php`. 
If there is another check of the session and the logged in user is redirected back to `member.php` you have found the cause of the redirect loop.

Comment: I like your last update. It was nice :D

Comment: @ErmanBelegu: What should i say? I was a little surprised.:D

Answer (score 3):

You have to start the session before you can begin interacting with `$_SESSION` variables. Put `session_start()` as the very first line.

As written now, your conditional will always evaluate to false and cause the redirect. Now why it's looping is not clear unless the redirect is re-directing to itself.